# How to tell which dropdown will be populated?

Tags: angular

```
<div *ngFor="let filterItem of fields[0].searchParameters;  let i = index" class="custom">
    <label>{{filterItem.fieldlabel}}</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <span [ngSwitch]="filterItem.fieldtype">
            <input ngDefaultControl [focusOnInit]="i"  *ngSwitchCase="'INPUT'" [ngModel]="selectedDevice" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" class="form-control-full" (change)="changeFilterValue(filterItem.value1)" (keydown)="keyDownFunction($event)"/>
             <select *ngSwitchCase="'LOV'"  class="form-control custom-select" type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterItem.value1" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (change)="changeFilterValue(filterItem)">
                <option value="" ></option>
                <option *ngFor="let value of filterItem.values" [(value)]="value.code" required>{{value.displayName}}</option>
            </select> 

             <select *ngSwitchCase="'LOVD'"  class="form-control custom-select" type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterItem.value1" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (change)="changeFilterValue(filterItem)">
                <option value="" ></option>
                <option [hidden]="filterItem.defaultvalue1!=selectedLabel" *ngFor="let value of filterItem.values" [(value)]="value.code" required>{{value.displayName}}</option>
            </select> 
        </span></div></div>
```

Right now i have method :

```
  changeFilterValue(value: any) {
    this.selectedLabel = value.fieldlabel;
    console.log('selected label',this.selectedLabel);
    //this.selectFilterEmit.emit(this.selectedFilter);
  }
```

But i dont know what dropdown i change. Any suggestion how can i detect that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass in the dropdown in the method call

```
(change)="changeFilterValue(filterItem, dropdownId)"
```

And switch based on that in your method

```js
changeFilterValue(value: any, dropdownId: int) {
  switch(dropdownId) {
    case 0:
      // do for dropdown with ID 0
      break;
    default:
      // do for default
      break;
  }
}
```

If you just want to emit which dropdown you don't need a switch you can just pass the ID (or whatever you want to pass in as the identifying parameter) to the part of your code that needs it.

Comment: thats then fixed data and if i add in database more records i need to change frontend and and more cases

Comment: Without knowing more about the application that is a difficult question to answer, like I said in my answer you don't have to use a switch, you could pass the dropdown identifier on to something else to handle, or use it as a field in an object/part of an API call - you would need to provide more detail to know how to handle this

Comment: I have setup in database and im using ngFor for displaying all dropdowns. Some of them depends on other. So i want to tell some dropdown that is depending on other and populate it when i select that first one. Is it clearer anything now? so for all of them im using same ngFor but display different data, and thats why i need to know what depend on what and populate it.

Comment: i can add some additional field for every of them and for example add master and child to know what depends on what. But because im in ngFor i dont know how to tell child that is depend on parent and populate it only if parent is selected

Comment: I think that this is becoming beyond the scope of this question. You should ask another question and provide the information necessary in that. That way other people are more likely to see it and help you get it answered

Comment: so u dont have any suggestions ?

Comment: It would be beyond the scope of the question you have asked here - if you ask another question and post enough information to answer then I may be able to suggest something. But currently there is not enough information and the comments section is not the place to get questions answered

Comment: i explained in my question what im trying to do, i dont know whats the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150744/discussion-between-0mpurdy-and-none).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have two different functions for two different dropdowns.